# Категории изменчивости функции (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

Когда какую волатильность выставлять у функции (VOLATILE, STABLE, IMMUTABLE)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Объяснение в документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-volatility.html)

Выставлять необходимо минимально необходимую. От этого зависит, что оптимизатор сможет полезного сделать. Например, выполнить функцию один раз заранее и потом пользоваться только результатом.

- Изменчивая функция (`VOLATILE`) может делать всё, что угодно, в том    числе, модифицировать базу данных. Она может возвращать различные    результаты при нескольких вызовах с одинаковыми аргументами. Оптимизатор не делает никаких предположений о поведении таких функций. В запросе, использующем изменчивую функцию, она будет вычисляться заново для каждой строки, когда потребуется её результат.
- Стабильная функция (`STABLE`) не может модифицировать базу данных и    гарантированно возвращает одинаковый результат, получая одинаковые    аргументы, для всех строк в одном операторе. Эта характеристика    позволяет оптимизатору заменить множество вызовов этой функции одним.    В частности, выражение, содержащее такую функцию, можно безопасно    использовать в условии поиска по индексу. (Так как при поиске по    индексу целевое значение вычисляется только один раз, а не для каждой    строки, использовать функцию с характеристикой `VOLATILE` в условии   поиска по индексу нельзя.)
- Постоянная функция (`IMMUTABLE`) не может модифицировать базу данных и    гарантированно всегда возвращает одинаковые результаты для одних и   тех же аргументов. Эта характеристика позволяет оптимизатору    предварительно вычислить функцию, когда она вызывается в запросе с   постоянными аргументами. Например, запрос вида `SELECT ... WHERE x = 2 + 2` можно упростить до `SELECT ... WHERE x = 4`, так как нижележащая функция оператора сложения помечена как IMMUTABLE.
  И ещё по таким функциям можно строить функциональные индексы.