# sql select возвращает null когда я вызываю функцию в условии, которая создаёт и возвращает id этой записи

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Как получить запись по id, где id возвращает функция, которая создаёт запись.

select fields from table where id = create_record(); - возвращает null

select create_record() возвращает id созданной записи

Comment: Добавьте минимальный воспроизводимый пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Пока непонятно, что вы делаете.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вы в хотите вставить запись и тут же вернуть ее из базы. Можете посмотреть на данный пример

```
CREATE FUNCTION sch.table_add(
    in_column_1 BIGINT,
    in_column_2 TEXT
)  
RETURNS TABLE (
    id BIGINT,
    column_1 BIGINT,
    column_2 TEXT
)
AS $$
DECLARE 
      _id BIGINT;
      result sch.table%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO sch.table(
        id,
        column_1, 
        column_2

    )
    VALUES (
        in_id,
        in_column_1, 
        in_column_2
    )
    RETURNING id INTO _id;
    
    RETURN QUERY SELECT 
        sch.table.id,
        sch.table.column_1,
        sch.table.column_2
    FROM sch.table
    WHERE 
        sch.table.id = _id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create temp table foo (i int);

create or replace function create_record() returns int as $$ 
  begin 
    raise notice 'call';
    insert into foo values (1);
    return 1;
  end 
$$ language plpgsql;

insert into foo values (1),(5);

select * from foo where i = create_record();
NOTICE:  call
NOTICE:  call
 i 
---
 1

select count(*) from foo;
 count 
-------
 4
```

Удивительно или нет? Так и должно быть.

Поскольку функция выполняет операцию записи - она должна быть [`volatile`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/546127/203622). А поскольку функция `volatile` - планировщик обязан вызывать её для каждой проверяемой строки и по той же самой `volatile` причине невозможно выполнить функцию и затем сделать `index scan` по этому значению - это будет ошибочное поведение, `volatile` функция имеет право возвращать разные результаты на каждый вызов (`random` - пример `volatile` функции).

То есть, в общем-то, уже всё равно что запрос не увидит результат insert - запрос вовсе ведёт себя не так, как вы бы того хотели.

---

Отдельно про то, почему запрос не увидит созданные строки: это особенность MVCC модели. Для корректного определения видимости строки используется снэпшот mvcc, ключевыми в контексте этого вопроса моментами в нём являются:

- номера транзакций, добавившие и удалившие запись - с этой позиции всё хорошо, запись не удалялась, добавлялась в этой транзакции
- значения command counter аналогично добавления и удаления - счётчика команд в транзакции. Счётчик команд штука очень нужная, чтобы можно было корректно в транзакции делать update и видеть в результате соответствующий результат, а не старую и новую версии строк.

И вот как раз на счётчике команд и спотыкаемся. Весь select выполняется в одном и том же снэпшоте mvcc и потому не увидит результат insert в хранимке - результат этого insert ещё не виден в этой команде. Иначе бы очень странно начали работать, например, `insert into tablename select ... from tablename where ...`

---

Правильным же подходом будет возвращать из хранимки не только `id`, но сразу данные всей строки.

```
create or replace function create_record_row() 
  returns foo -- имя таблицы это ещё и композитный тип данных, описывающий строку таблицы
as $$ 
  declare
    res foo%rowtype
  begin 
    insert into foo values (1) returning * into res;
    return res;
  end 
$$ language plpgsql;

select i from create_record_row();
```